# OpenCV frame data is nil on the second pass

Tags: c++, opencv

I am on a loop processing frames with OpenCV. Something like this:

```
VideoCapture cap(pathC);

  while(true) {
    cap >> cur;

    if(cur.data == NULL) {
      break;
    }

   // do something with cur
  }
```

when that loop ends, I need to process all frames again, so I have another loop exactly like this one but first I have to position the video on the first frame. Something like this:

```
  // I have tried all these methods to put cap on frame 0
  // cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO, 0);
  cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0);
  // cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 0);

  // in theory the video is on frame 0 now, do the loop

  while(true) {
    cap >> cur;

    if(cur.data == NULL) {
      break;
    }

       // do something with cur
   }
```

the problem is that `cur.data` at this second loop is `nil`.

printing cur to console on both cases gives me this

**first loop**

```
 {
  1124024336

  2

  1072

  1920

  0x04390010

  0x04973810

  0x04390010

  0x04973810

  0x04973810

  <nil>

   {
    0x27d33dac

  }
   {
    0x27d33dd4

     ([0] = 5760, [1] = 3)
  }
}
```

**second loop**

```
 {
  1124024336

  2

  <nil>

  1920

  <nil>

  <nil>

  <nil>

  <nil>

  <nil>

  <nil>

   {
    0x27d33dac

  }
   {
    0x27d33dd4

     ([0] = 5760, [1] = 3)
  }
}
```

So, something is wrong with the object on the second pass. It appears to have lost a lot of stuff.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced similar problem. It happens when there is some corruption in video data or header. Hence, problem occurs while setting to a frame number manually. 
What I did to fix is after first pass, close the video. While starting for second pass, instead of setting position to 0, just open the video again, it will open video with cursor at 0 and read without problem.

Comment: this is what I did and worked but I was trying to find a solution that was not that lame and because of the overhead to read the file again. Anyway, it worked. THANKS:

Comment: :) glad it helped. If it worked, you can upvote /accept as answer, it will help others to know answers validity. Again, set function has similar overhead like opening video and anyway you have to read frame again unless you save or store frames. If you are not dealing with steaming video, this is best solution as you won't have to store or save frames.

Comment: I have to test also the other answer. Yours is not exactly a solution but a hack. Anyway, if there is no real solution I will accept yours. :)

Comment: Thanks. It is a bug of OpenCV on IOS.

Comment: :) Hi RubberDuck, I prefer to see it as a problem rather than bug. It can happen on any OS. If the index / part of  data / some I-frames are corrupt, then it becomes difficult to read a frame from random time-code. There are already few bugs locked on OpenCV site also. But I will be happy to see a solution coming :D

Comment: Ok, but in this case is a bug because the problem happens on the iOS version and same code with the same video works fine on OSX. Bugs happen 

Comment: Ha ha ha, in this case, you are absolutely right. I have some bad experience with corrupt videos.. occupational hazard :D lol

Comment: you have to take a vacation! 

Answer (score 0):

I just tested an exact copy of your code, and it worked just fine. I would guess it has something to do with the platform you are running your code at, or the format/compression of the video file.

I tested with the C++ interface `cv::VideoCapture.set(...)` and the C one `cvSetCaptureProperty(...)`. Both worked just fine. The second loop iterated over all the frames like in the first one.

**My Setup:**

- **File format**: .avi
- **Video properties**: Total of 646 frames, at 20fps.
- **Compression/codec**: ffdshow.
- **OpenCV's version**: 2.49, x64 build.
- **Environment**: VS2013, Windows 8.1.

**My suggestions:**

1. Try using an uncompressed file in avi format. If this works, the problem then might be with OpenCV not supporting setting the properties of video files in certain formats/codecs. This would not be a surprise, to be honest. I recall having problems with some codecs in the past, even though I had them properly installed in my PC. The one that has always worked, though, is ffdshow.
2. Try using the C interface I just mentioned above. I remember having both behaving differently in version 2.42. Some videos I had would just open with the C interface.
3. Building your own version of the library (using cmake) might also be an option.

Please let me know if any of these suggestions helped.

Comment: Thanks. I am using MP4 videos, using H264 codec. I am running this on iOS. I will try what you say and return here as soon as I have some results. Thanks.